Cloning PERC H310 RAID 1 to non RAID SATA disk
I have a Windows 10 PC with the OS drive being 2 SAS drives on a Dell PERC H310 as a mirror.
I want to remove the RAID and install a single SATA SSD. I have some programs to which I have no installation medium, so I would require a clone without reinstall.
I tried Seagate and WD versions of True Image, but the drive would get stuck in a repair loop after startup. I have tried different PCs and different drives.
I need to know a cloning software that will work, bearing in mind that I am moving from a RAID to a non RAID setup.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Welcome to Superuser. Questions asking that we recommend software are off topic. Please read the HELP section to better understand this site and what are and are not allowed topics.

OK an update. I had broken the mirror as the replacement pc didn't have space to mount both drives, then I used another H310 controller that was flashed to IT mode to copy the 2nd drive from the mirror. Not sure if the controller made a difference as I had another H310 but it kept causing the pc to stop during the boot process. I used clonezilla, but found the latest version would not copy the raid so had to get an older version, in the end it worked. So got it working but cant say if it was clonezilla or the H310 in IT mode that made the difference.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
